# Showing charge on capacitor in circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Is there any way to show the charge on the plates of a capacitor in circuitikz? The manual does not say anything about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is `tikz` playing underneath, you can add `node`s with any content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0) 
        to node[below,pos=2]{$+q$} node[above,pos=2]{$+$} (0.5,0) 
        to [C, l^=$C$] (2.5,0) 
        to node[below,pos=-1]{$-q$} node[above,pos=-1]{$-$} (3,0) ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem. One suggestion, instead of `[C, l^=$C$]` you can also use `[C = $C$]`.